# Button not hiding when function is called from another class programmatically [Swift 3]

Tags: swift, user-interface, button

So I have a View Controller with a button that I only want visible if all three textfields are filled, within each class, where a change happens, I put:

```
ViewController().checkDoneButton()
```

Then the function is:

```
func checkDoneButton(){
    if (textField1.text != "" && textField2.text != "" && textField3.text != ""){
        doneButton.isHidden = false
        print("Done!")
    }
}
```

The console prints "Done!", but the button isn't visible. But if I summon the checkDoneButton() function using a button from the same View Controller, the button shows up. If anyone one can help that would be awesome. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling this `checkDoneButton` from background Thread for sure, can you post where you are calling this method?

Comment: `ViewController().checkDoneButton()` ?? Why are you creating a new object?? You should keep the instance of your other view controller and call checkDoneButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with this.

```
ViewController().checkDoneButton()
```

`ViewController()` creates a new instance of `ViewController`. You should be calling the `checkDoneButton()` on the same instance of ViewController that was presented.

You can use delegate pattern to overcome this problem. Here are some tutorials. [Tutorial 1](https://medium.com/compileswift/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) [Tutorial 2](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/) [Tutorial 3](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/)

Comment: That's right. we can use delegate or observer design pattern to avoid this problem.